# Do quoted MIME media type parameters allow escaped quotes?

Tags: escaping, mime

For an Internet MIME media type ([RFC 6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838)), a parameter may be quoted ([RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)). For example the following represents a value of `foobar`:

```
text/plain;test="foobar"
```

But am I allowed to include an escaped quote inside the quoted parameter? The following would represent a value of `foo"bar`:

```
text/plain;test="foo\"bar"
```

If so, then what about an escaped escape character? The following would represent a value of `foo\bar`:

```
text/plain;test="foo\\bar"
```

What about arbitrarily escaped characters? The following would represent a value of `fooxbar`, because the escape sequence `\x` would simply represent `x`:

```
text/plain;test="foo\xbar"
```

And just as importantly, which standard(s) defines this?

I would guess that at least escaped quotes and escaped backslashes are allowed, but I'm having trouble finding where this is specified.

Comment: I would expect these to be governed by the general RFC5322 grammar. I would not expect nontrivial variations to work reliably in clients, though, regardless of what the RFC says.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for alluding to another RFC, but other than that I have to say I don't see how your response could have been more vague. I mean that literally. There are no specifics at all in your reply, and if I wanted to make the sentence more vague, I don't know how I could have done it, other than removing the actual RFC number.

Comment: Let me rephrase that then. Figuring out what exactly the RFC stipulates is not going to be actually useful. The *de facto* standard you need to adhere to for interoperability is set by poorly implemented mail clients and browsers. If that's your goal, I would not expect anything like escaping to work reliably, regardless of whether the RFC is on your side. What are you actually hoping to accomplish?

Comment: (RFC5322 née 822 defines email headers. MIME obviously started out as an email standard, and body part header definitions etc build heavily on the existing standards for that. Browsers are probably better with RFC compliance than email clients, but that is not a very high bar.)

Comment: This sort of question isn't new. It isn't some strange, inescapable dilemma. 1) You start with what the de juro standards say, and implement that if you can. 2) You weigh whether there is some practice or de facto standard that has so much weight that it deserves diverging from the de juro standard. We do that with HTTP, HTML, CSS, or whatever, and we've been doing it for decades. My question was simply the first one: which standard governs this, and what does it say. You can answer #2 as a bonus. You indicate that RFC 5322 applies, didn't tell me what rules it gives.

Comment: "Figuring out what exactly the RFC stipulates is not going to be actually useful." We completely disagree. The RFC or other standard is _the place to start_. I'm trying to find the place to start. I welcome knowing where practice differs. But @tripleee you're telling me neither what the standards say, nor where practice differs; rather, you're complaining about the question and bemoaning the supposed futility of asking.

Comment: These are comments, not answers. I'll certainly try to find the time to answer, too, but that's going to take some time. In the meantime, thanks for clarifying your intentions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a complete answer yet, but I know that the [WhatWG says](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing-a-mime-type) that a MIME type parameter value must contain [HTTP quoted-string token code points](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#http-quoted-string-token-code-point). While it provides its own definitions, the WhatWG refers to [RFC 7230 § 3.2.6. Field Value Components](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6), which allows almost any escaping:

```
quoted-string  = DQUOTE *( qdtext / quoted-pair ) DQUOTE
qdtext         = HTAB / SP /%x21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E / obs-text
obs-text       = %x80-FF
quoted-pair    = "\" ( HTAB / SP / VCHAR / obs-text )
```

However it notes:

> A sender SHOULD NOT generate a quoted-pair in a quoted-string except where necessary to quote DQUOTE and backslash octets occurring within that string.

Note also that [RFC 5322 § 3.2.1.  Quoted characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.1) also has some rules. [RFC 6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838) governing media types mentions [RFC 6532 § 3.2. Syntax Extensions to RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532#section-3.2), although not clearly in the context of parameter values.